# what are the alternative for win32 to alarm,bzero,bcopy when porting c code

Tags: c, winapi, porting

im porting c code to windows 32 bit using visual studio express
now i have 3 functions that i can't find any alternatives in windows
they are:
alarm
bzero
bcopy
what are the equivalent methods in C win32 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From which platform are you porting to windows? Anyhow `bzero` and `bcopy` are depreciated since quite a while.

for bzero:

> This function is deprecated (marked as LEGACY in
>   POSIX.1-2001): use memset(3) in new
>   programs.  POSIX.1-2008 removes the
>   specifica-
>          tion of bzero().

for bcopy:

> This  function  is deprecated (marked as LEGACY in
>   POSIX.1-2001): use memcpy(3) or
>   memmove(3) in new programs.  Note that
>   the first
>          two arguments are interchanged for memcpy(3) and memmove(3). 
>   POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification
>   of bcopy().

So just fix your code and use the proposed replacements.

Answer (score 14):

alarm you are going to need to dig for the other two are:

```
#define bzero(b,len) (memset((b), '\0', (len)), (void) 0)  
#define bcopy(b1,b2,len) (memmove((b2), (b1), (len)), (void) 0)
```

Comment: The comma operator seems unnecessary, you could just cast the result of the functions to `void`.

Answer (score 4):

```
memcpy (output, input, size * sizeof (input[0]));
```

instead of

```
bcopy (input, output, size * sizeof (input[0]));
```

And

```
memset(m, 0, n * sizeof (gfloat));
```

instead of

```
bzero (m, n * sizeof (gfloat));
```

Answer (score 2):

for alarm have a look at Win32-API function `SetTimer()`.